# Lookup query exception while using USER_MODE

Tags: apex, unit-test, security, second-generation-packaging, queryexception

I am trying to create a 2GP package. But whenever I try to create a version by running and validating all test classes and metadata, the test class fails and shows such an error.

> "common.apex.runtime.impl.querywithaccess.UserModeQueryException: No
> such column 'User__c' on entity 'User_Company__c'. If you are
> attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after
> the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
> for the appropriate names."

This is the query I have written. Even when the code is pushed to a scratch org I still face the same issue.

```
[SELECT Name,User__c,Call__c,Email__c FROM User_Company__c WHERE User__c =: currentId WITH USER_MODE];
```

How can I get past this? Is this a known issue?

Comment: This is almost certainly because of missing permissions for the user running the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering is related to permissions when running the test class while packaging. It occurs because the test class operates within a different context. To resolve this, make sure that the permission set that you are packaging contains all the necessary permissions and simply specify the permission sets that the running user should utilize in the `sfdx-project.json` file within our project.

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "default": true,
      "package": "Sample App",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.0.1.NEXT",
      "ancestorVersion": "HIGHEST",
      "versionDescription": "Sample",
      "postInstallScript": "PostInstallScript",
      "apexTestAccess": {
        "permissionSets": [
          "Permission_Set_1",
          "Permission_Set_2"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```